# Is there any possibility for SharpPcap to block or limit packets?

Tags: c#, .net, winpcap, sharppcap

I want to make an application just like Bandwidth throttling in [this](http://www.netlimiter.com) application 
is it possible to achieve such thing with SharpPcap in C# ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know with WinPcap, you are only able to monitor or inject packets, but not to drop or manipulate packets. So **i would say no**, you can't achieve this with SharpPcap or WinPcap.

Comment: That seems fare, yat do you know any components or any open source library that cat do this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. All i ever did was sniffing/monitoring, but never trying to manipulate a given stream.